# Write portion of a split FileName to doc based on FileName

Tags: powershell, split

I need to split some file names to create reports (text doc). I am working on this but my code is becoming very convoluted, there is some logic i am failing to develop that could do this much cleaner.

File naming structure appears as such:

```
B00D09COGG.MAIN.PC_300_bob.jpg
B00D09COGG.PT01.PC_300_bob.jpg
B00EVI2MPI.MAIN.PC_300_bill.jpg
B01FKFF0OK.BACK.PC_300_bill.jpg
B00GB812OS.MAIN.PC_300_tom.jpg
```

I want to split the names up and write the first section (`B00D09COGG`, `B00EVI2MPI`, `B01FKFF0OK` and `B00GB812OS`) to a text doc named the last section (`bob`, `bill` and `tom`). Ultimately I need text docs named after each user name and containing the unique B00 codes associated with them.

End result should be three text docs titled `bob`, `bill` and `tom`

```
bill
----
B00EVI2MPI
B01FKFF0OK

bob
----
B00D09COGG

tom
----
B00GB812OS
```

What I have so far:

```
$b = GCI 'E:\Temp_Images'
foreach($c in $b){
$stylist = $c.BaseName.Split("_")[2]
echo $stylist
Out-File E:\Temp_Images\$stylist.txt
}
foreach($d in $b){
$ASIN = $d.BaseName.Split(".")[0]
$ASIN | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -like $stylist} | Write-Output E:\Temp_Images\$stylist.txt 
}
```

This is not working and I feel like I am taking the wrong approach.

Comment: While I can see some problems with your code as is, you should indicate what you _expect_ to see as a result, and what you _actually_ get. This reduces the chance of someone here misinterpreting your description of the problem and leading you down a wrong path. Please edit your question to include the additional information.

Comment: Good point Jeff, I will consider this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Use Add-Content to append to a file.

```
$b = GCI 'E:\Temp_Images'
$items = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.HashSet[Tuple[string,string]]'
foreach($d in $b){
    $stylist = $d.BaseName.Split("_")[2]
    $ASIN = $d.BaseName.Split(".")[0]

    $checkTuple = New-Object 'Tuple[string,string]'($stylist, $ASIN)
    if ( -not $items.Contains($checkTuple))
    {
        Add-Content ("E:\Temp_Images\" + $stylist + ".txt") $ASIN
        $items.Add($checkTuple)
    }     
}
```

Comment: Perfecto. I will have to add Add-Content to my arsenal, thanks!

Comment: I noticed this one doesnt look for only unique B00 codes, where would you inject that? I tried adding `$ASIN = $ASIN | Select -Unique` but that didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't have to...add content just creates or adds to file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'It doesn't have to'. My goal was to only get the unique B00 codes, i.e. no duplicates. In current state the code you provided writes duplicates.

Comment: You have records with the same stylist and isin?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Yes, they are in the example.

Comment: The combination of the two isn't unique in the example...do u need something to delete the distinct files up front?...the script isn't doing that but I can add it.

Comment: B00D09COGG.MAIN.PC_300_bob.jpg,B00D09COGG.PT01.PC_300_bob.jpg would be the unique ones by the ops standards.

Comment: i added duplicate checking

Comment: @Ctznkane525 thanks, this appears to be working. I am not very familiar with tuple, will this work if the number of files in `'E:\Temp_Images'` exceeds the example? Say there are 500 files and 10 user names, will it still function?

Comment: Yes...that's really small actually

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach. Might be a little more over the top then it needs to be but it collects all of information from the files and outputs to each text file once.

```
# You see
$rootFolder = "e:\temp_images"
# Use a regex match string to extract the code and name from each file
$regex = "(?<code>\w+)\..*_(?<user>\w+)"
# regex also doubles as a filter for files that do not match the structure
Get-ChildItem $rootFolder | Where-object{$_.BaseName -match $regex} | ForEach-Object{
    # Create a custom object of the code and name
    [pscustomobject]@{
        code = $matches.code
        user = $matches.user
    }
# Group on user 
} | Group-Object user | ForEach-Object{
    # Write the unique data to file for this name
    $_.Group.Code | Select-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Path "$rootFolder\$($_.Name).txt"
}
```

You need at least PSv3 for this to work.

It read all of the structured files in the folder `$rootFolder` and creates an object for each. Using your example:

```
code       name
----       ----
B00D09COGG bob 
B00D09COGG bob 
B00EVI2MPI bill
B01FKFF0OK bill
B00GB812OS tom
```

Then it groups them together:

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                          
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                          
    2 bob                       {@{code=B00D09COGG; name=bob}, @{code=B00D09COGG; name=bob}}                                                                                                   
    2 bill                      {@{code=B00EVI2MPI; name=bill}, @{code=B01FKFF0OK; name=bill}}                                                                                                 
    1 tom                       {@{code=B00GB812OS; name=tom}}
```

After that its pretty easy to isolate the unique values in each group and write them out to file.